BioJava - java.io.IOException: Structure 1LVZ not found in "C:\PDB files" and configured not to download
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bio_java_maven_hello_world</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
            <artifactId>biojava-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.biojava</groupId>
            <artifactId>biojava-structure</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

package org.example;

import org.biojava.nbio.structure.*;
import org.biojava.nbio.structure.io.LocalPDBDirectory;
import org.biojava.nbio.structure.io.PDBFileReader;

public class BioJavaPDBHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PDBFileReader pdbReader = new PDBFileReader();

            // Set the path to the local PDB file directory
            pdbReader.setPath("C:\\PDB files");
            pdbReader.setFetchBehavior(LocalPDBDirectory.FetchBehavior.LOCAL_ONLY);

            // Reading a structure by PDB code
            Structure structure = pdbReader.getStructureById("1LVZ"); // Example PDB code

            // Print the PDB ID
            System.out.println("PDB ID: " + structure.getPDBCode());

            // Print the title of the structure
            System.out.println("Title: " + structure.getPDBHeader().getTitle());

            // Print number of atoms in the structure
            System.out.println("ID : " + structure.getId());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=54171:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\git\bio_java_maven_hello_world\target\classes;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\biojava\biojava-core\5.4.0\biojava-core-5.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-slf4j-impl\2.13.1\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.1\log4j-api-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.13.1\log4j-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\biojava\biojava-structure\5.4.0\biojava-structure-5.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\rcsb\ciftools-java\0.7.1\ciftools-java-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.5\gson-2.8.5.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\rcsb\mmtf-api\1.0.9\mmtf-api-1.0.9.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\rcsb\mmtf-serialization\1.0.9\mmtf-serialization-1.0.9.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\msgpack\jackson-dataformat-msgpack\0.8.18\jackson-dataformat-msgpack-0.8.18.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\msgpack\msgpack-core\0.8.18\msgpack-core-0.8.18.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.9.3\jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.9\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\rcsb\mmtf-codec\1.0.9\mmtf-codec-1.0.9.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\biojava\biojava-alignment\5.4.0\biojava-alignment-5.4.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\biojava\thirdparty\forester\1.038\forester-1.038.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\org\jgrapht\jgrapht-core\1.1.0\jgrapht-core-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.0\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.3.0\jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.3.0\jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\pc\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.jar org.example.BioJavaPDBHelloWorld
20:43:37 [main] WARN  org.biojava.nbio.structure.align.util.UserConfiguration - Could not read dir from system property PDB_DIR or environment variable PDB_DIR, using system's temp directory C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.io.IOException: Structure 1LVZ not found in C:\PDB files and configured not to download.
    at org.biojava.nbio.structure.io.LocalPDBDirectory.downloadStructure(LocalPDBDirectory.java:447)
    at org.biojava.nbio.structure.io.LocalPDBDirectory.getInputStream(LocalPDBDirectory.java:353)
    at org.biojava.nbio.structure.io.LocalPDBDirectory.getStructureById(LocalPDBDirectory.java:327)
    at org.example.BioJavaPDBHelloWorld.main(BioJavaPDBHelloWorld.java:17)

Process finished with exit code 0

I have the file in the given location.
C:\PDB files>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is DEFD-2FA5

 Directory of C:\PDB files

24-Apr-24  08:42 PM    <DIR>          .
24-Apr-24  08:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
12-Apr-24  03:30 PM           309,420 1aqg.pdb
12-Apr-24  02:49 PM           124,335 1ejg.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:31 PM            27,378 1lb0.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:30 PM           316,872 1lvz.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:31 PM           229,311 1m23.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:32 PM            31,104 1niz.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:30 PM            78,165 1tor.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:30 PM            49,329 1tos.pdb
12-Apr-24  02:47 PM           130,491 1trz.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:33 PM            34,506 3cmh.pdb
12-Apr-24  03:35 PM           658,206 3ifn.pdb
12-Apr-24  02:36 PM            38,475 5awl.pdb
12-Apr-24  02:58 PM           439,344 6a5j.pdb
12-Apr-24  02:57 PM           118,098 7ur8.pdb
24-Apr-24  08:18 PM    <DIR>          data
              14 File(s)      2,585,034 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  31,268,425,728 bytes free

C:\PDB files>

So, why is BioJava not finding the file?

Maybe it's case-sensitive? Also - you don't want to put spaces in the folder and files names. Oftentimes you get problems because spaces need to be escaped or something.

You should really debug the code in the library. I think it's going to be trivial to find the problem. From the code and documentation alone I can see that you probably need to invoke pdbReader.addExtension(".pdb");

@StanislavBashkyrtsev, None of your suggestions achieved the expected result.

One of my suggestions was to debug the code - you see the stack trace, so you see where the problem is. That suggestion has to achieve the expected result ;)

The issue was due to the mismatch between the BioJava version and the JDK version.
I installed JDK 11 and BioJava 7.1.1.
Then, the exceptions were gone.
